# Why are there so many "char" types in ABAP when you have "string" type?

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

In the ABAP Dictionary, you can find data elements of "CHAR" types for almost all lengths, so here goes the question: what functionality have them **when you have a string element that can afford all the lengths?**

I am talking about those with specific length but having the same domain type.

Here I show **some** of them:

```
CHAR0001
CHAR0008
CHAR0010
CHAR0016
CHAR0032
CHAR004
CHAR005
CHAR006
CHAR0064
CHAR007
CHAR01
CHAR011
CHAR012
CHAR0128
CHAR02
CHAR022
CHAR0241
CHAR025
CHAR0256
CHAR03
CHAR04
CHAR05
CHAR060
CHAR07
CHAR08
CHAR101
CHAR102
CHAR1024
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have so many because of many reasons.

1. String type cannot be used as a primary key in a database (transparent) table.
2. When using a string type in one of the fields of a structure some implicit operations on the variables of such a structure type will not be possible for example by assignments to other fixed length structure.
3. By using a string type in a structure type you make it no longer a flat structure.
4. Some data migration interfaces like Direct Input **require** the load structure to be of a defined fixed length.

I think there are many more, but this was what I could think of in a short period of time.

Comment: STRING and RAWSTRING exist since [ABAP 4.6A](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abennews-46-strings.htm) (probably implemented in the DDIC at the same time), so there was no other solution than CHAR and RAW before that version.